# What does "this" refers to in the code below?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, bcrypt

I was looking at some tutorial, there I found a piece of code where I stuck.Please help me to understand this code.I have marked the questions in my comments.

`Code`

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next){    //this is a pre hook which is used.understood.

    var user = this; // what is the function of this?
    var SALT_FACTOR = 5;

    if(!user.isModified('password')){  //not understood.From where this function arises?I did not found this anywhere in mongoose tutorial/api.
        return next();
    } 

    bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_FACTOR, function(err, salt){

        if(err){
            return next(err);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "pre-save" middleware in Mongoose is *"document middleware"*.

[The documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#notes) states:

> ...in document middleware, `this` refers to the document being updated.

So `this` refers to the document to be saved.

This also provides a clue as to what `isModified` is: it's a document method that can be used to check if a particular field, `password` in this case, has been modified since the document was retrieved from the database earlier.

In the code you're posting, if the password hasn't been changed, there's not need to hash it again (using `bcrypt`), so that step is skipped by calling `next` and returning from the middleware.

`isModified` is documented here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-isModified

Comment: Thank you for clarifying my doubt :-)